# Can't Load Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am new to VirtualBox and to Ubuntu. I have a PC running Vista and am trying to install Ubuntu and then run NASA LINUX software.
In my first try I installed VirtualBox and set up a virtual computer named Ubuntu. Then I downloaded a Ubuntu ISO file. The first time wizard couldn't find the ISO file.  The Second try, I downloaded the ISO file and saved it to the desktop. The VirtualBox  could no longer use the first time wizard and I couldn't find CD/DVD in the menu.

Please help with some step.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mount CD/DVD image file via virtual machine settings:

[image]

Just mount the Ubuntu iso file there, and restart your virtual machine. If it's still not booting from the Live CD, check the boot order of your virtual machine.