# Ubuntu iso boot load stuck in Virtual Box

Tags: boot, virtualbox, windows-10, iso

Goal: Run Ubuntu via Virtual Box on Windows 10

Issue: Boot screen stuck at black screen:

[image]

immediately after the initial purple screen while starting reading from the downloaded ISO

[image]

ISO downloaded from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop (ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)

My OS:
[image]

Virtual Box Settings:
6.1
[image]

General

[image]

Display: 
Video Memory: 128MB
[image]

RAM: 4 GB

[image]

Processor: 4 Cores

[image]

Controller from where the ISO is being pulled:
[image: iso]

I have already disabled the Hyper-V and Virtual Machine Platform option from "Turn Windows featured on or off"

[image]

Before posting this question I have already gone through these links but found no success:

- [Cannot install Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on VirtualBox 6 on Windows 10 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130661/cannot-install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-on-virtualbox-6-on-windows-10-pro)
- [Ubuntu 16.04.2 in Virtual Box does not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927755/ubuntu-16-04-2-in-virtual-box-does-not-start)
- [Can't Load Ubuntu on VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277648/cant-load-ubuntu-on-virtualbox)
- [Virtual Box Won't Accept .ISO To Install OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144780/virtual-box-wont-accept-iso-to-install-os)

Can you share what I am missing in the basic first step of installation of Ubuntu iso in the Virtual box on Windows 10?

Even the logs of "Virtual Box" and "Event Viewer" of Windows are having no information on why this issue is coming.

Comment: Just disabling the virtual-hyper-v adapter did not work. Rather uninstalling, and thereby reboot of host windows, resolved for me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Virtualbox 6.0 instead of 6.1.

I had some issues with long initramfs loading on 6.0. It seems some issue with initramfs loading could be present on 6.1. You could also try to **Enable PAE/NX** on **System** -> **Processor** and **Enable VT-x/AMD-V**, **Enable Nested Paging** on **System** -> **Acceleration** tabs.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was able to move ahead with the 6.0 version. I was getting this error " Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87)" at first go with 6.0 but after I ran "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off" via cmd that error got fixed.

Comment: I went to version 6.0 (now unsupported) and tried all things here, still hung on black screen. I have Windows latest version with WSL2 but disabled it along with Virtual Machine Platform. What's left to try?

Answer (score 1):

@Ragav, do the hardware virtualization enabled? It seems software virtualization is disabled in version 6.1.

"Please also use version 6.0 if you need to run VMs with software virtualization, as this has been discontinued in 6.1. Version 6.0 will remain supported until July 2020."

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Please [edit] and include the link to the quote.